# how does a drag and drop view change programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Where do UIView objects get instantiated when I drag and drop them into the storyboard in Xcode? And when I create an outlet of an UIView object from the storyboard in the ViewController's class what am I doing exactly? Creating another instance of an UIView that also "points to the object in the storyboard"? Because if I change a property from the outlet I also change that same property of the object in the storyboard.

Comment: An outlet doesn't create another instance, it's a pointer to the one you have in the storyboard that will be instantiated at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The storyboard is just a visual appearance of an xml file. During compilation, the storyboard will be compiled to .xib Files and during runtime code will be executed that creates e.g. a UIButton instance and assigns it to the IBOutlet Property.

When you create an outlet in the view controller (you mean cmd-drag-and-drop it into the vc's interface don't you?), you do not instantiate an object, this will happen during runtime. It's only a special kind of property that will be created and connected to a visible element in Interface Builder. Special in that way that it is attributed as IBOutlet. IBOutlet means "this is a property and a UIView in the Interface Builder is (or at least can be) attached to it".

Let's make a short example:
You have a UI with a button and it's connected to your VC
[image]

Your vc:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Opening the storyboard in xml view will show that the ViewController is connected to a UI element:

```
<scene sceneID="s5g-Va-rCL">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="xkG-tv-x1p" customClass="MyViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="zM9-gD-jvN"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="rpt-g7-UaO"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="bJ6-Zc-BUd">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iHE-Sb-Hes">
                                <rect key="frame" x="277" y="60" width="46" height="30"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Button">
                                    <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                </state>
                            </button>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="myButton" destination="iHE-Sb-Hes" id="0tI-Cr-cDZ"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dWo-Es-1mt" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1092" y="628"/>
        </scene>
```

The most interesting here is the following line:

```
<outlet property="myButton" destination="iHE-Sb-Hes" id="0tI-Cr-cDZ"/>
```

The destination "iHE-Sb-Hes" is the button's id declared just a few lines above. This is the connection definition between the UIViewController and the UIView that will be compiled into code and instantiated during runtime.

Usually, you should not worry about how the UI elements will be created in detail. When a UIViewController is pushed, it's view will be loaded and viewDidLoad: will be called and all your UI objects are there. You can write your own view-loader and yes, you can create the entire UI in code.
For custom view loading override loadView as described here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Summing things up:

- Although I referenced the XML here, usually do not touch the storyboard's xml, since it was made to be edited by IB. A git merge is fine but do not start to write the UI's view in plain xml like you would do on Android or Windows XAML
- The runtime will generate all your view objects that you defined in IB, this should be o.k. for 99.99% and you should start jumping in with your code in lifecycle hooks like viewDidLoad: or viewWillAppear:
- If you are not fine with the default UIView loading, override UIViewController's loadView, but there are only very rare cases where you have to do so

Answer (score 0):

OK, First you really need to read OOP guide books (specifically objective-c ones of you want to programme in objective-c). I would go to apple developer Library to start understanding the basic concepts in iOS dev.

For your question, an instance of `UIView` can be instantiated in two ways:

1) By code when you write `[[UIView alloc] init]` (you can init with the `frame` also)

2) By IB (StoryBoard) when you drag and drop a `UIView` into a `ViewController`, this UIView will get instantiated when the `ViewController` will be loaded.

When you create an `IBOutlet` from a `UIView` (or any other object), you basically create a pointer to the object you dragged and dropped into that `UIVIewController`. If you change any of the attributes of that `IBOutlet` it is changing the attribute of that object in the IB. By creating a `IBOutlet` **you are not** initialising any objects at all (the `ViewController` you placed that object in is responsible for this) you only create a pointe to that object.

Answer (score 0):

The point is **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization**. Your interface is just serialized in a XML file (storyboard, xib or nib).